# VBA copy number of Rows to new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

as a beginner to coding and VBA in specific im currently trying to automate as much worksteps as im able to, mainly to get into it. So for now i got a set of >50 Excel Workbooks and the "simple" task to collect the number of Datapoints (one row for each datapoint) in each and pass this value to a new workbook . What i built together until now is this (the credit for basic construct goes fully to [Henrik Schiffner](https://professor-excel.com/merge-excel-files-combine-workbooks-one-file/), i used it for several other operations):

```
Sub count_rows()
    'Define variables:
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    'This Step is not mandatory of course but quite comfortable to choose 
    'the workbooks to work with
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)        

    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True        
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.count
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            LastRow = tempWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count - 1
            MsgBox LastRow
        Next tempWorkSheet            

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sourceWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next i

    mainWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

This gives me the correct Value from each file in the prompted message box. However, im failing to grab the LasRow value and simply copy it to the mainWorkbook. Aim is to have one value after another in one column (lets say "A"). Failure is on different levels like: Searching for the last empty row in mainWorkbook with:

```
destinationRow = mainWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp) + 1
```

Or even to give the lastRow Value to any spot in mainWorkbooks with e.g.:

```
mainWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(destinationRow) = LastRow
```

Or

```
LastRow.Copy After:=XXXX
```

Im pretty sure im misunderstanding a basic concept of VBA, so it would be awesome to get a short explanation why my operations did not work out instead of just getting a working code.
However, adding the name of each Workbook as a header for its value would be magnificent!

Comment: Just a note: If you declare `Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook` then `mainWorkbook` is of type `Variant` you must specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim mainWorkbook As Workbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook`  same for your other variables. • Also row counting variables need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim LastRow As Long`.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the last empty row in mainWorkbook would use the `UsedRange` property of `Worksheet` object; this returns a `Range` object which you then access the `Address` property of. You then want to use the `Split()` function which will take your string and place each substring seperated by a delimiter ($ in this case) into an index of an array. For your purposes you want the 4th index which will be the last row in the UsedRange:

```
'The MsgBox's should help you understand what is happening with this code
MsgBox (mainWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address)
lastRow = Split(mainWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address, "$")(4)
MsgBox (lastRow)
```

I am a little confused by what you meant with, "give the lastRow Value to any spot in mainWorkbooks." If you meant you would like the set the value of a cell in your mainWorkbook to the value of the lastRow, you would use:

```
mainWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = lastRow
```

And I am not sure what you are trying to do with: `LastRow.Copy After:=XXXX`. Your LastRow variable is an Integer `Dim LastRow As Integer`. An Integer Data Type cannot use the `Copy` Method. I mostly use the `.Copy After:=` Method to copy one worksheet and paste it after another. If that is your goal:

```
'Copy Sheet1 and place it after the last sheet in the workbook
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count)
```

Otherwise, if you could explain your goal with that I would be happy to help.

As a beginner to code and VBA I would suggest a few things. The first is to do research on OOP (Object Oriented Programming). A very basic breakdown is that you have Objects which then have Methods and Properties (for example the CoffeMug object has a .Temperature property and a .Spill Method, and timsMug and tinasMug are both CoffeeMug objects). I love OOP, but it takes a while to get a truly deep understanding of how it works. After that though, it's a lot of fun and really powerful.

Other than that, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/ to learn about VBA. I use the Excel section and Language Reference section all the time.

Comment: Hey Tyler, first thx for your answer! Indeed, I wasnt aware that you cant use .Copy Method with integers, but i guess its normal beginner confusion as i dont see a reason why this shouldnt be possible in general. Anyway, this was just an example of what i tried. I also tried the one you suggested (`BLABLA.Value = lastRow`) in different ways before. Such trys would always give me a "Subscript out of Range Error 9", as just did your MsgBox code no matter if i implemented it in my code or in a new module.

Comment: And sorry for not being clear enough. My code above gives me the number of datapoints in several Workbooks (this is the lastRow variable) one after another in a massagebox (just for controlling, i dont need the MsgBox). I want to copy the lastRow variable to mainWorkbook to have a column where one lastRow follows the other. By saying "to any spot in mainWorkbook" i ment that im not even able to pass one lastRow variable to mainWorkbook, not to speak of hundreds organized one after another in a column. Hope that helps? :)

Comment: I would start debugging. Open a new spreadsheet that's just for testing. Try `Cells(1,1).Value = "Hi"` Then qualify the Cells Object with a Sheet Object `Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value`. Then qualify the Sheet Object with a Workbook object, and then start introducing variables one at a time and MsgBox each one before using it (for the objects you will have to MsgBox the Name property of them (Ex: `MsgBox(mainWorkbook.Name)`)). Change "Hi" to a String Variable, make your Sheet Qualifier a Sheet Object Variable, etc. See if that helps you determine the cause of your error.

Comment: Hey, after debugging for a couple of hours step by step as you suggested i got a working code. Just in case anybody is looking for, defining a active worksheet as object and usage of `mainWorksheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = LastRow` within the for each loop will do the job. Anyway, thanks Tyler for i will keep this strategy in mind when it comes to the next projects!